# Github pages doesn't load (only white screen)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I deploy my react-app into github pages, turns out to view only white and blank page.

Solutions i tried

Changing  to 
adding basename={window.location.pathname || ""

APP.JS

```
import "./App.css";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import { HashRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ProjectsPage from "./pages/ProjectsPage";

function App() {
  return (
    <HashRouter basename={window.location.pathname || ""}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/projects" element={<ProjectsPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Project.JS

```
import React from "react";
import { ProjectWrapper, ProjectLink } from "./ProjectLinksStyles";
const ProjectsLinks = () => {
  return (
    <ProjectWrapper>
      <ProjectLink to="/projects">See my web design projects here!</ProjectLink>
    </ProjectWrapper>
  );
};

export default ProjectsLinks;
```